# VB6 application connecting to mapi

Tags: windows, vb6

I have created a VB6 application which contains a service to basically send and receive emails,the service uses a service account and mapi profile configured in Windows 2003 serverR2.

This was working when both exchange server and domain account were in the same network.  Once the exchange server got changed the service is unable to send or receive emails giving error

> Microsoft Exchange is not available.  Either there are network problems or the Exchange computer is down for maintenance. [Microsoft Exchange Information Store - [MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER(8004011D)]], Collaboration Data Objects.

I have searched this error but I wasn't able to gather all as the explanation is for same network.
Anyone could you please advice what can I do to resolve this ?
Thanks,

Comment: MAPI/CDO have been discontinued as Exchange APIs in recent versions.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj619283(v=exchg.160).aspx

Answer (score 0):

MAPI has been discontinued by Microsift as suggested by @bob77 also. 
I would recommend to use SMTP or EWS.

That being said if you still want to go with it.
Please find the working code below:

```
   Set objMAPI = New MAPI.Session
  objMAPI.Logon ShowDialog:=False, NewSession:=False, ProfileInfo:=gobjINI.gstrExchangeServer & vbLf & gobjINI.gstrProfile

 'Add a new mesage to the OUtbo Messages Collection
 Set objMSG = objMAPI.Outbox.Messages.Add

 Set fsoMy_File_Sys_Obj = New FileSystemObject

 'Add the recipient list specified in INI File
 'Check if this is a multiple Recipient List (names or groups seperated by semicolons!)
 If InStr(1, Recipients, ";") Then
  objMSG.Recipients.AddMultiple Recipients, CdoTo
  objMSG.Recipients.Resolve
 Else
  'This section is for handling of single recipient name
  'Be aware that this may be an email group list name !
  Set objRecipients = objMSG.Recipients.Add(Recipients)
  objRecipients.Resolve
 End If

'Add an attachment if needed
If Attachment_Name <> "" Then
    bolAttach_File_Exists = fsoMy_File_Sys_Obj.FileExists(Attachment_Path)
    If bolAttach_File_Exists = True Then
        'Open the attachment file and add it to the message text
        Set tsAttachment = fsoMy_File_Sys_Obj.OpenTextFile(Attachment_Path)
        Do While Not tsAttachment.AtEndOfStream
            strAttachment_Read = tsAttachment.ReadLine
            Message = Message & strAttachment_Read & vbCrLf
        Loop
        tsAttachment.Close
    Else
        gobjMAPI.MailSend gobjINI.gstrMailRecipients, "Email Send - Attachment Addition", "Attempted To Attach A File That Does Not Exist", "", ""
    End If
End If

 'Add Subject Line, Message Content and Send Message
 objMSG.Subject = Subject
 objMSG.Text = Message
 objMSG.Importance = mapiHigh

 'The Update method adds all our assignments to collecttion
 objMSG.Update

 'Now let's actually send the message
 objMSG.Send

 'End MAPI Session
 objMAPI.Logoff
 Set objMAPI = Nothing
```